# Get Tabel Name From the model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im tring to get table name from the model using getTable() method but i can show the table name

`$model->getTable()`

Comment: Hello, could you share more information? What is $model? What do you get when you use the method?

Comment: If `$model` is an instance of `Model.php`, then that code should return `models`. By convention, the table name should be the plural of the Model's name, so `Model` would be `models`, `User` would be `users`, etc. What, specifically, is not working with your code? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75184440/edit) and include more details.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an instance of the model, you may call the `getTable()` method as described in the [API reference](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getTable).

```
<?php

$table = $model->getTable();    // string
```

If you do not have an instance of the model, using the `app()` helper is the simplest solution.

```
<?php

$table = app(\App\Models\User::class)->getTable();
```